# Error when using d3.svg.line to generate an SVG polyline from GeoJSON LIneString data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Per the suggestion in the d3.js API documentation [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-svg_polyline), I'm trying to use d3.svg.line to generate an SVG polyline from coordinate data describing a LineString in GeoJSON format. However, when I do this I get an error in my browser's JavaScript console as follows:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="[object SVGLineElement]"
```

The GeoJSON data looks like this.

test.json

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "0" },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [ -122.1219348702,42.3351232329 ],
        [ -122.05927795103516,43.04825098762893 ],
        [ -117.5980213906,43.0866974143 ]
      ]
    }
  }
] }
```

The JavaScript looks like this, which follows the example in the documentation not too far below where I linked above in the section titled "Path Data Generators".

app.js

```
var projection = d3.geo.albers()
  .scale(2000)
  .center([-20,47]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return projection(d)[0]; })
  .y(function(d) { return projection(d)[1]; })
  .interpolate("linear");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var g = svg.append("g");

d3.json("test.json", function(json) {
  g.selectAll("path")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", line);
```

I'm able to generate polygons just fine... I just run into trouble when trying to generate polylines. Any suggestions?!

Comment: FYI, I got around this by using path instead of line when setting the "d" attribute on the path and setting fill: none for the path. However, I'm still interested to know why I was getting the error given this is the suggested use in the d3.js documentation.